# Why am I able to use the names in the std namespace even though I'm "using namespace std;"?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std

Isn't there already a max function in the algorithm header file?
And by `using namespace std;`, I'm importing the function to the global namespace (which takes to arguments, and in this case both would be integers, so it shouldn't be an overload).

So why isn't there any naming conflict?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int max(int a, int b)
{
    return (a > b) ? a : b;
}

int main()
{
    cout << max(5, 10) << endl;
}
```

Comment: You signature is different to the std::max version so you have provided an overload

Comment: You've explicitly provided an overload of `max()` in the global namespace with arguments that exactly match the call of `max()` in `main()`. In picking candidate functions to match that call, that overload is preferred over any templated function, like `std::max()`.  Also, `using namespace std` does not "import" functions like `std::max()` into the global namespace. It causes the compiler to use names in `std` as candidates.  `std:max()` does provide a candidate to match `max(5,10)` but so does the overload you supplied, and by rules of the language, is the preferred match.

Comment: This question is an excellent demonstration of why `using namespace std` is usually a terrible idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So why isn't there any naming conflict?

You're declaring a non-template `max`, and [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) is a set of overloaded function templates, so they're all overloaded. And the non-template version declared in the global namespace is selected in [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function) here.

> F1 is determined to be a better function than F2 if implicit
> conversions for all arguments of F1 are not worse than the implicit
> conversions for all arguments of F2, and
>
> ...
>
> 4. or, if not that, F1 is a non-template function while F2 is a
>    template specialization
>
> ...

Answer (score 5):

> And by `using namespace std` I'm importing the function to the global namespace

This is a common misconception. Nothing is imported.  In fact, placing the directive `using namespace std;` in the global namespace means that when a name is looked up in the global namespace, that name is also looked up in namespace `std`.

The `std::max` function is still in the namespace `std`, it is not in the global namespace.

Your declaration of `max` is fine as you are declaring `::max` which is a separate entity to `std::max`.

When you make the unqualified function call `max`, the name is looked up in the global namespace, and also in `namespace std`.

The results of both of those lookups lead to an *overload set* consisting of all signatures of functions called `::max` and `std::max`.

Then overload resolution selects the best match out of the overload set for the arguments provided, and it turns out that `::max` is a better match because a non-template function is a better match than a function template, all other things being equal.